# CSS multiple nth-child without pattern into one selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with 5 column under a div with Id. I want to do add click handler by Jquery on the 2, 3 and 5 column. I can do something like this

```
$('#myDiv td:nth-child(2), #myDiv td:nth-child(2n+3)').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

I was wondering is there any other or better way to combine this two nth-child together.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `2n+3`?

Comment: getting the 3rd and 5th column

Comment: This will return every second element starting the 3rd one. 3, 5, 7, 9 etc.

Comment: yes. I know that. Since I have 5 columns here, I will get 3 and 5. Do you know any better way other than 2n+3?

Comment: You can't simplify them anymore than they currently are.

Comment: Is there a problem with the way it currently is?

Comment: It works. I was curious is there any better/ efficient way.

Comment: Perhaps adding classes provides more readable and maintainable code?

Comment: Thanks for your thought. I was curious to know more about :nth-child

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is probably the best way:

```
$('#myDiv td').filter(':nth-child(2), :nth-child(3), :nth-child(5)')...
```

There's a shorter way but I don't recommend it because it's really coupled with the DOM *(assuming you have only 5 elements like you said in the comments)*.

```
$('#myDiv td:not(:nth-child(3n - 5))')...
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Q9fbQ/)

Comment: I got your point but my question is about nth-child. multiple items.

Comment: Well this answers your question. There's no way of doing this with one :nth-child selector. Even if there was a complicated calculation that would return 2,3,5 it's not advisable because it's really not readable and coupled with the HTML structure

Comment: @JoshC He already said in the comments to the OP that he have only 5 columns

Comment: @Itay my bad. 1+ Great solution then

Comment: @Itay. I have 5 and I like your math solution 3n-5.

Comment: Did you mean `.filter()` and not `.find()` in the first example?